# Twig doesn't support do / while?

Tags: php, symfony, while-loop, twig, do-while

The problem is that Twig doesn't support `while`(repeat) loop, Twig support only For loop!

I wrote a code and I believe it can be done only using while loop!

My code in php is :

```
$j=0;
$i=0;
do {
    $i=$i+3;
    for ($x=$j;$x=$i;$x++) {
        <h1> t[x]</h1>
    }
}while ($i >= $max);
```

I can't translate it to Twig , because twig doesn't support do/while

Another example here is a for loop in php:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {

}
```

When translated to twig is:

```
{% for i in 0..10 %}

{% endfor %}
```

My question is what if the php code is:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++++)
```

What if it's `($x=$x+3)` instead of `($x=$x+1)`

Comment: What would be the purpose of translating this to Twig? It's a templating engine, it shouldn't execute excessive logic. Maybe if you added a bit information about the big picture we can set you on the right path.

Comment: the problem is i cant make that code in the backend (controller) , i have to do it in the view , cuz each 3 items must be printed together ...

Comment: Create a service that groups backend data into a format suitable for the view to simply iterate over it and output. Avoid any complex logic inside the template itself.

Comment: i have no idea how to do that so .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Twig built-in `..` operator is just syntactic sugar for the range function (with a step of 1, or -1 if the start is greater than the end):

```
{% for i in 0..3 %}
    {{ i }},
{% endfor %}
```

Therefore, you can rewrite it with a `range` operator, that can also take a 3rd parameter - `step`

```
{% for i in range(0, 6, 2) %}
    {{ i }},
{% endfor %}

{# outputs 0, 2, 4, 6, #}
```

from: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/range.html